# Why would a loaded PHP extension fail on class instantiation?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have some code which is resizing images, using either [Imagick](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) or GD, depending what's available on the server.

I'm testing for availability of each using the `extension_loaded()` function.

```
if (extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    $image = new Imagick();
    ...
}
```

I have one user reporting that they are receiving:

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found

What circumstances would result in the Imagick extension being loaded but the class not available? How should I be testing to make my code more robust?

Comment: are you sure that's the right class name?

Comment: yeah I didn't follow the imagick API but I have actually the same problem on one of my server, I think there is more then one API around so maybe that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: always do the checks in a case-insensitive manner (make the string lowercase before comparing it)

2: don't check for the library, check for features. Maybe it has a library version that's buggy or has other function names

3: **in php.ini you may disable some functions explicitly by name** so I think you should resort to point #2 and check with function_exists instead of extension_*

Also, take a look at `/var/log/apache2/errors` or the equivalent on that client's server to check for any internal error generated by the ImageMagick extension ([segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) or other types of low-level errors should get reported in there...)

Comment: In this case it turns out that there's an old version of the library that is function- rather than class-based. Testing for features (in this case using `class_exists()` as Danny Croft suggested, avoids the problem. Good advice.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the class exists also?

> class_exists("Imagick")

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitive?

'imagick'  and `Imagick`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    yum install ImageMagick
    yum install ImageMagick-devel
    pecl install imagick
    echo "extension=imagick.so" > /etc/php.d/imagick.ini
    service httpd restart [/etc/init.d/httpd restart]
    php -m | grep imagick
```

[Reference](http://phpbugs.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/install-imagemagick-with-php-imagick-extension/)